# Get pair number of given shelf number

Tags: sequences-and-series, applications

I work at a warehouse, and have shelves organized in that way:

```
(number means shelf number and "--" means aisle between shelves)

1    2
--  --
3    4 
5    6
--  --
7    8
9    10
--  --
11   12
```

etc.

Pair 1-3 represent aisle #1, pair 2-4 represent aisle #2, pair 5-7 represent aisle #3 and so on. There is no aisle between 3 and 5 because it's the same shelf.

I wonder if there is an elegant formula to get aisle number for a given shelf? Say it must return 1 for 1 or 3, return 2 for 2 or 4, 5 for 9-11 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok writing some scripts, drawing big images, and running to my local library counting shelves there hopefully solved this question. Given the Shelf number $s$ you get the aisle by:

$$ a = 2\left\lfloor \frac{s-1}{4} \right\rfloor + ({(s-1)}\mod  2) +1 $$

Comment: This formula gives $a=1$ when $s=2$, but according to the question shelf $2$ is on aisle $2$.

Comment: Fail, I thought the aisles are connected. The other formula is a bit ugly. Edit: no wait didn't read it again!

Comment: Isn't it still return aisle 1 for shelf 2?

Comment: sorry you right the right thing should be modulo if you know that

Comment: im just confusing myself

Comment: Now it returns 2 for shelves 2,4,5,7. But it looks prospective anyway.

Comment: Ok for 1,3 it returns 1 for 2,4 it returns 2. For 5,7 it retuns 3, and for 6,8 it returns 4????

Comment: You're a wizard - it works perfectly! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: puhh your question was just too difficult!